# Subprocess remove files

Tags: python

How would I do the following:

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split('rm {}'.format(os.path.join('/tmp', '*.mp4'))))
```

Basically, I want to remove all mp4 files in my tmp folder. But I get the following error:

```
rm: /tmp/*.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use glob?

```
import glob
import os
for fl in glob.glob("/tmp/*.mp4"):
    os.remove(fl)
```

No need to shell out to another process.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is interpreted by the shell. The [call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) function by default has the `shell` parameter set to `False` which means that it will directly `exec` the command you give it and not use a shell. This means that the usually shell globbing will not take place. If you want that behaviour, you'll need to add `shell = True` to your `call` invocation. However, this also brings with it all the regular hassles of shells, spaces and escaping so be warned.

If I wanted to trash a directory, I'd probably use [rmtree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) rather than shelling out.